# Install container engine on build-server on the fly

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-server-2022

We use the [Azure DevOps build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines)s. In one pipeline we now want to add a build-step to build a container-image with something like [Docker@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2) or similar. As a preparation for this we have also added a previous [DockerInstaller@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-installer-v0)-step so that docker is available.
Problem: When we run the pipeline on our build-server we get the error `error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.32/images/create?fromImage=mcr.microsoft.com%2Fdotnet%2Faspnet&tag=7.0: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.` . This may be true because we did not install a docker daemon on the build-server. However, we do not want to install anything on the build-server. We just want to rely that the `DockerInstaller@0`-step makes the `docker` available on the fly in a working way.

Is that possible without installing anything "globally" on the build-server as preparation?

Notes:

- On the build-server we just want to do `docker build ...` and we do *not* want to run any container with something like `docker run ...`.
- In the `...\_work\_tool\docker-stable\17.9.0-ce\x64`-folder from the pipeline-task on the build-server there is just a 19mb `docker.exe`-file without anything else. When running `docker.exe pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0` in this folder in an elevated cmd we get the same error-message.

Comment: Docker requires a running daemon to do anything. The CLI is just for interacting with the daemon.

Comment: If this is the case, then why is there a [DockerInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines)-step and the documentation for [Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml#requirements) says in the requirements, that there are no demands?